# What are the consequences of negating the Godel sentence in a formal system?

Tags: logic, incompleteness

What is wrong with the following argument?

Let $F = T + ¬G_T$, where $T$ is an effectively generated formal system and $G_T$ is its Godel sentence.

Then, it is possible to prove within $F$ the First Incompleteness Theorem for $T$: $Con(T) \Rightarrow G_T$, just by utilising the axioms for $T$.

But from this the contrapositive follows: $¬G_T \Rightarrow ¬Con(T)$.

So in F it is possible to prove $¬Con(T)$, since $¬G_T$ is an axiom.

But it then follows that $¬Con(F)$, since the same contradiction that is derivable in $T$ is also derivable in $F$ by restricting ourselves to the axioms for $T$.

So any formal system that is of the form $F = T + ¬G_T$ is inconsistent.

Comment: it would be helpful if you explained what you mean by the = and + sign in your equation. you are mixing and matching operators and not forming well-formed formulas

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy F is the formal system that has the axioms of T plus the axiom of the negation of the Godel sentence of T.

Comment: This is a good question (and absolutely should **not** have been downvoted, it's an important subtlety), but it's also a duplicate. See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2165704/puzzle-does-the-following-prove-that-pa-is-inconsistent, or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4179554/puzzle-does-the-following-prove-that-pa-is-inconsistent-part-2?noredirect=1&lq=1, or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287867/how-to-think-about-theories-that-prove-their-own-inconsistency.

Comment: Actually that last one is **not** quite the same question, although it's closely related; my first link should have been my dupe target.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly. You have shown that $F$ can formally prove $\neg \text{Con}(F)$ but you can't deduce from it that $F$ is inconsistent (which is a meta-statement). You seem to believe that the following meta-theorem is true :

"If $F \vdash \neg \text{Con}(F)$ then $F$ is inconsistent"

but how would you prove such a thing ?

Comment: Well, I just thought the definition of $¬Con(F)$ is that there exists a proof in $F$ of some generic contradictory statement like $¬(0=0)$.

Comment: @RojusLukauskas Yes, but you have to distinguish between $\neg Con(F)$ (or, $\neg Con(F)$ "holds in reality") and $F\vdash\neg Con(F)$ (which is what you have here).

Comment: @RojusLukauskas - compare with the comments to your [previous question (now deleted)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4816697/does-the-negation-of-a-consistency-sentence-of-a-formal-system-f-imply-the-exist) regarding your professor's comment that the deductive step (5) in your argument is not valid.